# IO Operation is blocking my UI Thread and also another Background Thread

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading

I am a novice in Threads, but I want to know how to order thread execution in my scenario, and is the following :

- UI Thread : Windows Form Background
- Thread : Kind of print daemon
  implemented with recursive methods
- IO Operation : a StreamWriter that do
  the job of File.AppendText()

When I execute my main app.exe, sometimes it launchs the Windows Forms and the execution process in the task manager (app.exe), in some oportunities its just launchs the execution process in background.

How can I determine the behavior of launching UI, I have to stablish a priority or somewhat else?

My code snippets :

In Form Load (app.exe) it calls the follow function OnStart() :

```
Dim start As ThreadStart = New ThreadStart(AddressOf Writing)
                Hilo = New Thread(start) 
                Hilo.IsBackground = True
                Hilo.Start()
```

Hilo is a global variable type of Thread declared on Form.vb

Writting is a function that read database and execute some actions, when it finish execution it abort the thread calling OnStop() :

```
Protected Sub OnStop()
        Try
            If Not (Hilo Is Nothing) And Hilo.IsAlive Then
                Hilo.Abort()
            End If
            objWriter.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------")
            objWriter.Close()
        Catch exc As Exception
            LogEventSI(exc.Message & " - " & exc.StackTrace)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

ObjWriter is the StreamWriter that write lines in a .txt its scope is in all the app.exe

I'm using framework 2.0 and any answers could be writted in C# or Vb.Net

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry for my bad english, but I think the question is not really clear, what could I do for make it more understandable?

Comment: I see nothing that would cause any blocking. Can you provide the code where you think the UI thread is getting blocked?

Comment: OnStart() repeat it selfs because is a recursive method

Comment: Ahh...so are you saying that you figured out the problem?

Comment: yes, I found that using recursive methods become a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I become with a solution, using a recursive method with a condition when I need to call OnStart() function, then if conditions is not satisfied it calls to OnStop().

Thanks